# Office 365 API: To access the other user emails

Tags: office365

I am developing an application in which I want to generates some reports for all different email account. I am trying to access these all accounts using Global Admin account . I am able to access my emails but when i try to access the emails of different users than it shows me error...

"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."

I am using "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2" authority to access the https://outlook.office365.com/..

Pls Help me...

Thanks

Comment: Jason, I try to follow the as you mention Building Daemon or services app, but got error after successful login Error code is :403 "Forbidden"...I use the same request using Graph explorer and its work for that but from my application it return error 403.. I don't know where i made mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The REST APIs do not support delegated or shared access. You can't access another user's information by authenticating as yourself via the auth code grant flow. You may want to investigate [using client credentials auth flow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx), where your admin account can grant the application access to all mailboxes in your org.

Comment: Jason, I try to follow the as you mention Building Daemon or services app, but got error after successful login Error code is :403 "Forbidden"...I use the same request using Graph explorer and its work for that but from my application it return error 403.. I don't know where i made mistake.

Thanks

Comment: What request returns that error, and do you have the response headers?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jason, But somehow I manage to solve that issue.  Thanks for your help